# Install an OS on Dell Inspiron 7559

Tags: linux, windows-10, laptop, arch-linux, dell-inspiron

Tried Win 10 official iso (Pro) - hangs on "Getting files ready for installation (67%)", tried many times

Tried Arch linux - it did install but soon failed to boot (because of some ELAN drivers I guess, I didn't install any)

Tried Ubuntu - hangs on both Live session and Install. No way to diagnose.

Shall I claim warranty from my reseller, i.e. return the laptop? Or is there any OS that can be installed other than Dell's recovery image (which I don't want to use since it's bloated with Dell's software and forces you to use home edition single language)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after destroying my efi partition and recovery partition, I was facing a similar scenario. I also did not like the bloatware that comes with the recovery image.

I tried my luck by going to the dell support site, entering my service code and under Drivers & Downloads and used the OS Recovery that comes with it. This surprisingly did not include any of the bloatware that comes with the default OS loaded

It is Windows 10 Home though...

Ubuntu I recall you have to do the following to get it working: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2307347

Arch Linux is the where I deleted my own efi boot partition. PEBKAC

Comment: good thing! thx for your update